# Understanding a question on vector bundles

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-bundles, principal-bundles

I have the following question on vector bundles which I am struggling to understand:

> Consider the tangent bundle $TS^2$ with an inner product on the fibres, and let $Y\subset TS^2$ consist of all the tangent vectors of unit length. Show that $TS^2$ induces on $Y$ the structure of a principal $S^1$ bundle over $S^2$.

I am struggling to understand the last part of the question. Is this regarding $TS^2$ over $Y$ as a vector bundle, which is to have the same structure group as "the structure of $S^1$ bundle over $S^2$"? Though I am not certain as to what it. I thought it might be a vector bundle or principal bundle, but $S^1$ has a lower dimension than $S^2$ so being a bundle 'over' $S^2$ doesn't quite make sense to me.

Comment: I think it means that $Y$ is regarded as a bundle over $S^2$, where the fibers are $S^1$. Since $S^2$ is 2-dimensional, the set of unit vectors in each tangent space form a circle. That is the intuitive idea.

Comment: @Nick Thank you for your reply. That makes sense intuitively, though I realised I missed out a key word: 'principal $S^1$ bundle over $S^2$' To me, that should mean that $S^1$ is here a group and is acting on something with a smooth free right action. I cannot decide whether it makes sense for that thing to be $TS^2$, $S^2$.

Comment: It should act on $Y$, right, since that's the bundle? By rotation. For a given angle $\theta$, the inner product lets you make sense of rotation by $\theta$ in each tangent space simultaneously.

Comment: @Nick It helps that everything here is orientable. The inner product alone wouldn't be able to distinguish $\theta$ from $-\theta$.

Comment: Oh I see! S1 as a group acts on Y, which looks like a sphere with a circle at each point. So indeed when one takes the quotient $Y/S^1 \cong S^2$, hence why the base is $S^2$ :)